# GAE webapp2 change parameter of get method automatically

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi I passed a flag with get method like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='flag' value='1'>
<input type='submit'>
```

Since I used 'flag' as flag, it should be changed when the page is automatically refreshed.

```
flag = cgi.escape(self.request.get('flag'))
if flag == '1':
    Some code to refresh and set flag='2'
```

Can I have some proper ways to refresh and change parameter?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Google App Engine. You might want to tagged it differently.

Comment: im asking some google app engine skills....
I may use ajax or http redirection...  
but I want to use some code useable in GAE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the form via a `jinja2` template -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates for detailed instructions on how to set this up.

So if your template file contains e.g

```
<input type='hidden' name='flag' value={( flag_value }}>
<input type='submit'>
```

you can render it (after using the Jinja2 environment to get the `template` object) in your handler with

```
self.response.write(template.render({'flag_value': flag}))
```

and as long as you've appropriately updated your Python variable `flag` you should obtain the effect you request.

One appropriate way to update `flag` (assuming you always want to increment by one, but keep `flag` as a string, not an integer) might be, e.g

```
flag = str(1 + int(flag))
```

Comment: is it possible with only python and webapp2?

Comment: @sounbumsong, sure, you can reimplement templating yourself in Python (after all, jinja2's all-Python, which proves it's possible to do so:-), but why would you **want** to, when jinja2 comes with GAE both in prod and in the SDK?  Anyway this specific case is simple enough that you could just use the standard library, https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings , e.g with `value=${flag_value}` as the placeholder in the template string, and the `substitute` method of stdlib template strings in lieu of jinja's `render`.